Nginx still displays default `index.html` after symbolic link removed from `sites-enabled`
I have unlinked the symbolic link default from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled, and then run systemctl reload nginx.
However, if I send a CURL request to the server, I still get the default html back.
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>

Why is this? It should be a 404 not found.
Here's the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file.
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        gzip on;

        server {
                listen 80;
                listen [::]:80;
                server_name example.uk;

                location /download {
                        root /static-files;

                        add_header X-uri "$uri" always;

                        try_files /example-file.txt =404;
                }
        }

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


(This is mostly comment but space limited)

Why is this?

We have no idea.
You could check your nginx log files to see if the reload was successful. To see if your requests are actually being handled by the webserver you think this is coming from.
You didn't tell us what other configs exist on the site. "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled" implies the Debian-type configuration - but you didn't tell us the provenance of the configuration nor the platform it sits on. Did you check from the root configuration file (nginx.conf) that site configurations are only being loaded from this location?
You could try changing the content of the page which allow you to rule out caching issues outside of the webserver, DNS misconfiguration and routing issues.
You could check any other site configurations to see if they are poitning at the same root.
You could try re-implementing the default website pointing to a different root / content.

Fair comments, I will add my config
